# DataTemplate delivering correct result for first item in list and then incorect for second item in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have the following Item in my control:

```
<Canvas Name="canvasTrack" Height="{Binding CanvasHeight}" Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}"> 
   <ItemsControl  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentSegments}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BegSegmentTemplate}">
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

And the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BegSegmentTemplate">
    <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Margin="{Binding EntryPoint}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I then have it bound to an `ObservableCollection` that has two items in it.  When I run the program two ellipses appear.  The first one is in the correct spot on my canvas but the second one is in a 'random' spot.  I have checked the numbers that are being bound and everything appears normal.  What could I be missing?

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Scratch my previous comment as I see you have already cleaned it up.  I will attempt to format it better in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, an `ItemsControl` loops through it's items and puts each of them in a `StackPanel`, so your end markup basically looks like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <Ellipse Margin="{Binding EntryPoint}" />
        </ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <Ellipse Margin="{Binding EntryPoint}" />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

If you want to loop through items and place them on a `Canvas` based on some bound value, you  need to overwrite the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to use a `Canvas` instead of a `StackPanel`, and apply your positioning in the `ItemContainerStyle` so that you are setting the positioning on the `ContentPresenter`, and not the `Ellipse`

This will make your end result look like:

```
<Canvas>
    <ContentPresenter Margin="{Binding EntryPoint}">
        <Ellipse />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter Margin="{Binding EntryPoint}">
        <Ellipse />
    </ContentPresenter>
</Canvas>
```

Some example code to achieve this would be:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSegments}">

    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding EntryPoint}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

See [this link](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) for some samples using an `ItemsControl`

Comment: Thanks, that makes a ton of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying an `ItemsPanel` in your `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```